# Menu background is not visible on device

Tags: menu, android-emulator, android

I want to set background image for menu buttons. I can see the image on emulator, but when I run the app on device it does not show any background image, but only transparent white background. 
I have set the background like this

protected void setMenuBackground(){

```
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory( new Factory() {  
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase( "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView" ) ) {
                try {  
                    LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();  
                    final View view = f.createView( name, null, attrs );  

                    new Handler().post( new Runnable() {  
                        public void run () {  
                               view.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.menubuttons_bg );
                              }
                    } );  
                return view;
            }
                catch ( InflateException e ) {}
                catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {}  
           } 
            return null;
}});
```

}

Comment: Can any one answer this question ?

Answer (score 0):

here

```
view.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.menubuttons_bg );
```

you are setting the background on the view

I think you are looking to set it on the button

Comment: Please tell me the correct way, if I am missing any thing. If I am missing, then how it shows correctly on emulator ?